# Reading from file with different line length

Tags: c#

does anyone know how to read from file to array(container with inheritance) when the line length is different?(I hope language barrier won't make any problems:))

```
 Sportas Skaitymas(Sportas sportas)
        {
            SportininkasCointainer sportininkai = new SportininkasCointainer();
            KomandaContainer komandos = new KomandaContainer();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Duomenys.txt"))
            {
                string line = null;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] values;

                    values = line.Split(';');                    
                    string a = values[0];
                    string b = values[1];
                    string c = values[2];
                    string d = values[3];
                    string e = values[4];
                    string f = values[5];
                    string g = values[6];

                    switch (values.Length)
                    {
                        case 7:
                            Krepsininkas krepsininkas = new Krepsininkas(a, b, c, int.Parse(d), int.Parse(e), int.Parse(f), int.Parse(g));
                            sportininkai.AddSportinkas(krepsininkas as Krepsininkas);
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            Futbolininkas futbolininkas = new Futbolininkas(a, b, c, int.Parse(d), int.Parse(e), int.Parse(f));
                            sportininkai.AddSportinkas(futbolininkas as Futbolininkas);
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            Komanda komanda = new Komanda(a, b, c, int.Parse(d));
                            komandos.AddKomanda(komanda);
                            break;
                    }  
                }
            return sportas;
    }
```

I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Use a [`List<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: Well, I "can't" use lists in this exercise..

Comment: I'd recommend mentioning that in the question. What is the problem with your current method using `.Split()`? Or is the array to be applied in some other way?

Comment: The problem is "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array." if array length is 5,

Comment: Also good to mention in the question. The obvious solution seems to be to move the parts that read those optional values into point in the code where you've checked they exist.

Comment: It crashes because values 4,5,6 has no imput

Comment: You should check the length of the array before accessing any index in the array. You do a `line.Split()` which results in an array of length 5, yet you access index 5 (which is the sixth element), without checking whether it exists or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
string a = values.Length > 0 ? values[0] : "";
string b = values.Length > 1 ? values[1] : "";
```

Here, string is only set when value is present else it will be ""

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's smart :)